# How to add a variable in views context DJANGO?

Tags: django

I have this code but it does not work when I try to put `a` to the context view. I am a beginner in this. Thank you very much for your help!

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext
import csv

a = []
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in spamreader:
        a.append(row)

def home (request):
    return render_to_response("home.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: All that needs to be inside the home function.

Comment: It sill does not work it shows: unindent does not match any outer indentation level.

Comment: Then you need to fix your indentation. That is a basic requirement of Python.

Comment: Sorry for being dumb but how am i supposed to do that?

Answer (score 1):

About identation, you need to use 4 spaces to program Python.

Try this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext
import csv

def get_data():
    with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        a = []
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
        for row in spamreader:
            a.append(row)
        return {'csvdata': a}

def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home.html', get_data(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then you should be able to call `a` with `csvdata` name in template.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `a` is a name in the global scope and therefore isn't a part of `locals()`. Instead of `locals()`, explicitly pass the arguments you need for the template (e.g. `a`).

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext
import csv

def home(request):
    with data as csv.reader( open('myfile.csv', 'r'), delimiter=','):
        return render_to_response('home.html', {'data': data}, context_instance=RequestContext)
```

`data` in the code I wrote should contain a list of rows.